# Solidity: return array in a public method

Tags: solidity

I am trying to create a public funcion that returns an array,
this is the error

> Return argument type mapping(uint256 => struct ItemList.Item storage
>   ref) is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first
>   return variable) uint256[] memory.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
contract ItemList {
    uint public itemCount = 0;
    mapping(uint256 => Item) public items;

    event ItemCreated (
        uint id,
        string proofdocument
    );

    struct Item {
        uint id;
        string proofdocument;
    }

    constructor() public {
    }

    function createItem(string memory _proofdocument) public {
        itemCount++;
        items[itemCount] = Item(itemCount, _proofdocument);
        emit ItemCreated(itemCount, _proofdocument);
    }

    function getItems() public pure returns(uint256[] memory ) {
        return items; <----------ERROR
    }
}
```

Thanks Andrea

Comment: Well, yeah. The error message is pretty clear. What were you _expecting_ to happen? What values would be returned?

Comment: it should returns an array :-( 
i can't see the error sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get every item in the loop via `web3.js` library

```js
const array = []
for (let i = 0; i < itemCount; itemCount += 1) {
    array.push(contract.getItem(i)) // where getItem do items[I] in solidity
}
```

Or you can use `pragma experimental` version:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract ItemList {
    uint public itemCount = 0;

    struct Item {
        uint id;
        string proofdocument;
    }
    Item[] items;

    constructor() public {}

    function createItem(string memory _proofdocument) public {
        itemCount++;
        items.push(Item(itemCount, _proofdocument));
    }

    function getItems() external view returns(Item[] memory) {
        return items;
    }
}
```