# Try to return an array in a for loop

Tags: solidity

I am very new to Solidity, so sorry for the silly question. I am trying to add an element of a struct and then return it, here is my code:

```
struct Flat {
    uint256 priceInWei;
    address currentOccupant;
    bool flatIsAvailable;
}


Flat[8] public flatDB;

modifier landlordOnly() {
    require(msg.sender == landlordAddress);
    _;
}

constructor() public {
landlordAddress = msg.sender;
for (uint i=0; i<8; i++) {
    flatDB[i].flatIsAvailable = true;
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        flatDB[i].priceInWei = 0.1 ether;
    } else {
        flatDB[i].priceInWei = 0.2 ether;
    }
  }
}

uint256[] array;
    
function getFlatDB() payable public returns (uint256) {
    
    for (uint i=0; i<8; i++) {
        array.push(flatDB[i].priceInWei);
    }
    return array;
}
```

But when I try to compile I have an error at line 41:

```
TypeError: Return argument type uint256[] storage ref is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) uint256. return array; ^---^
```

Can someone explain me what's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Just type cast your randomized result to uint256

Comment: This may answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56469332/solidity-return-array-in-a-public-method

Comment: @Ashok I tried to do `return uint256(array)` but then I have `Explicit type conversion not allowed from uint256[] storage ref to uint256

Comment: @Ashok you put as recommend answer, my question..

Comment: Sorry edited it

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the return type you have (`uint256`) doesn't correspond to the type you're actually trying to return (`uint256[]`). Try rewriting your `getFlatDB` function in the following way:

```
function getFlatDB() payable public returns (uint256[]) {
    uint256[] memory array = new uint256[](8);
    for (uint i=0; i<8; i++) {
        array[i] = flatDB[i].priceInWei;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Note how we declare the temporary fixed size return array inside the function with `memory` keyword.